# Redshift permission error "GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied"

Tags: permissions, redshift

I followed the answer here: [How do I kill redshift?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961815/how-do-i-kill-redshift). I ran this command

```
redshift -o 6500
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Trying location provider `geoclue2'...
Using provider `geoclue2'.
Unable to start GeoClue client:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Geolocation 
disabled for UID 1000. Unable to connect to GeoClue. 
Unable to get location from provider.
```

How to set it so it has access to my geolocation and sets the brightness?

Comment: That command you are typing in should be `redshift -O 6500`.  You can try to set it manually:  https://askubuntu.com/a/951469/231142  I have included the link to find your lat and long that you can put in your `~/.config/redshift.conf` file.

Answer (score 8):

The quick workaround is use capital `-O` (One shot *manual* mode) instead of small one `-o` (One shot mode) i.e:

```
redshift -O 6500
```

[GeoClue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geoclue/geoclue/wikis/home) is the Geolocation service which needs the location service enabled. So make sure that Location service is enabled from Settings > Privacy:

> [image]

I was getting the same error, after creating configuration file (`~/.config/redshift.conf`) as explained at [official site](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) and now `redshift` and `redshift-gtk` is working fine:

```
; Global settings for redshift
[redshift]
; Set the day and night screen temperatures
temp-day=5700
temp-night=3500

; Enable/Disable a smooth transition between day and night
; 0 will cause a direct change from day to night screen temperature.
; 1 will gradually increase or decrease the screen temperature.
transition=1

; Set the screen brightness. Default is 1.0.
;brightness=0.9
; It is also possible to use different settings for day and night
; since version 1.8.
;brightness-day=0.7
;brightness-night=0.4
; Set the screen gamma (for all colors, or each color channel
; individually)
gamma=0.8
;gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8
; This can also be set individually for day and night since
; version 1.10.
;gamma-day=0.8:0.7:0.8
;gamma-night=0.6

; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue', 'geoclue2', 'manual'
; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values.
; The location provider settings are in a different section.
location-provider=manual

; Set the adjustment-method: 'randr', 'vidmode'
; type 'redshift -m list' to see all possible values.
; 'randr' is the preferred method, 'vidmode' is an older API.
; but works in some cases when 'randr' does not.
; The adjustment method settings are in a different section.
adjustment-method=randr

; Configuration of the location-provider:
; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings.
; ex: 'redshift -l manual:help'
; Keep in mind that longitudes west of Greenwich (e.g. the Americas)
; are negative numbers.
[manual]
lat=48.1
lon=11.6

; Configuration of the adjustment-method
; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings.
; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'
; In this example, randr is configured to adjust screen 1.
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually the
; second screen. If this option is not specified, Redshift will try
; to adjust _all_ screens.
[randr]
screen=0
```

You can fed latitude and longitude of your location manually @ 45<sup>th</sup> (`lat=`) and 46<sup>th</sup> (`lon=`) line for above mentioned configuration file. Note that I needed to change `screen=1` to `screen=0` in the last line.

Answer (score -1):

```
"redshift - slove geoclue2 redshift not working error" 
#redshift/software/extension geoclue2 not working/stopping error
#ERROR:
 Trying location provider geoclue2'... Using provider geoclue2'.
 Unable to connect to GeoClue.
 Unable to get location from provider.
 #OR:
  Unable to start GeoClue client:
  GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Geolocation 
  disabled for UID 1000. Unable to connect to GeoClue. 
  Unable to get location from provider.

#solution1) turn on the location:
e.g:
 Gnome Settings > Privacy > location
 #unfortunatly most Desktop environment settings doesn't have location ON/OFF feature, but dont worry, we can install gnome settings manually:
   sudo apt install gnome-control-center
   #then enable location services
    gnome control center > privacy > location services

#solution2) install geoclue2
e.g:
 #on fedora:
  sudo dnf install geoclue2 geoclue2-libs geoclue2-devel geoclue2-demos
 #on debian:
  sudo apt install geoclue-2.0


#solution3) run redshift with sudo
e.g:
 sudo redshift


#solution4) add these lines to  /etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf:
e.g:
 [redshift]
 allowed=true
 system=false
 users=

 #then run:
  sudo service geoclue restart

#solution5) create a configuaration file(THIS SOLUTION WORKED FOR ME)
e.g:
 #YOU NEED TO SET latitude(45th line) and longitude(46th line) manually
  #visit this site the file your lat & lon: https://www.latlong.net/
 #goto ~/.config directory & created a file "redshift.conf" and put below lines in the redshift configuration file(~/.config/redshift.conf)
; Global settings for redshift
[redshift]
; Set the day and night screen temperatures
temp-day=5700
temp-night=3500

; Enable/Disable a smooth transition between day and night
; 0 will cause a direct change from day to night screen temperature.
; 1 will gradually increase or decrease the screen temperature.
transition=1

; Set the screen brightness. Default is 1.0.
;brightness=0.9
; It is also possible to use different settings for day and night
; since version 1.8.
;brightness-day=0.7
;brightness-night=0.4
; Set the screen gamma (for all colors, or each color channel
; individually)
gamma=0.8
;gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8
; This can also be set individually for day and night since
; version 1.10.
;gamma-day=0.8:0.7:0.8
;gamma-night=0.6

; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue', 'geoclue2', 'manual'
; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values.
; The location provider settings are in a different section.
location-provider=manual

; Set the adjustment-method: 'randr', 'vidmode'
; type 'redshift -m list' to see all possible values.
; 'randr' is the preferred method, 'vidmode' is an older API.
; but works in some cases when 'randr' does not.
; The adjustment method settings are in a different section.
adjustment-method=randr

; Configuration of the location-provider:
; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings.
; ex: 'redshift -l manual:help'
; Keep in mind that longitudes west of Greenwich (e.g. the Americas)
; are negative numbers.
[manual]
lat=48.1
lon=11.6

; Configuration of the adjustment-method
; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings.
; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'
; In this example, randr is configured to adjust screen 1.
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually the
; second screen. If this option is not specified, Redshift will try
; to adjust _all_ screens.
[randr]
screen=0



#solution6) run redshift in background(if above solutions didn't work? you can try this):
 #remove redshift-gtk extension from panel and stop autostarting redshift in startup programs
 #then add this startup command to run redshift in background after login
   redshift -l 7:81 -t 5700:3600 -g 0.8 -m randr -v
   #you can change 0.8 to adust brightness(0.1 - 1)



#links:
 https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/445
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061453/redshift-permission-error-gdbus-errororg-freedesktop-dbus-error-accessdenied


----------
```

Comment: [Edit] and format your answer correctly. Answer duplicated here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1380193/348964

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1190235)